# How to get connection/network usage time on android

Tags: android

I need to get the time spent by the phone on 2G networks, 3G networks or data disconnected.
I searched the android references but couldn't find any solution.
Is there any method to get these stats?

I thought to use a listener to detect when the network/connection type changes and use a counter for 2G time, 3G time and Disconnected time. But i'd like to know if there is a better/simpler way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

How about an connection check like

```
public boolean isOnline() {
        // check if an internet connection is present
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (!(netInfo != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && cm
                .getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())) {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And then counting time ...

Dont forget the  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` in the Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way, the [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) only contains data statistics. You have to register a BroadcastReceiver for the [CONNECTIVITY_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges) intent.
You also have to listen for phone startup (RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED).
Shutdown is trickier. I would add a listener for TIMER_TICK, this will give you a minute precise uptime, which is enough for this application. You can process this at startup, subtracting the downtime from the last network state's counter.